# Building localized mobile applications with jQueryMobile - need inputs

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

All,

I'm building a localized mobile application in which I'm using a unicode font(of my language) and have created numerous json files, At a rough estimate my "JSON" files comes around 25 MB.

I just want to know, is there any way to optimize the size of files when we use localized unicode fonts?.

Can anyone share your thoughts here?.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Can anyone shed some light? - Thanks in advance!, Dave